# Cannot import androidx.compose.ui.platform.DensityAmbient (DensityAmbient)

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, import, dependencies

I'm trying to import import androidx.compose.ui.platform.DensityAmbient
and I can't. the DensityAmbient is red, seems like the class doesn't exist.
[image: android studio import]
This is my gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.21"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-ripple:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
}
```

does anyone have any idea (maybe version mismatch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using **LocalDensity** see: [Jetpack Compose Density](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Density)

Comment: Yeap, that works!!! lots changed in the SDK

Answer (score 1):

dont exist this class in this package

see the documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary